# How to create Parcel In?

Tags: java, android

I have a class called MusicFile, its constructor is:

```
protected MusicFile(Parcel in) {
        Title = in.readString();
        Album = in.readString();
        Artist = in.readString();
        Path = in.readString();
        Genre = in.readString();
        Data = in.readString();
        artistID = in.readInt();
        if (in.readByte() == 0) {
            AlbumID = null;
        } else {
            AlbumID = in.readLong();
        }
        albumCover = in.readParcelable(Uri.class.getClassLoader());
    }
```

But now that I've made it to extend `Parcelable`, I cannot just create a new `MusicFile` like so:

`MusicFile musicFile = new MusicFile();`

Because it requires `Parcel In`.

How can I create a new Music file now? I've tried the following:

`
Parcel parcel = New Parcel();

MusicFile musicFile = new MusicFile(parcel);
`

However that doesnt seem to work.  I get the following error: `'Parcel(long)' is not public in 'android.os.Parcel'. Cannot be accessed from outside package`

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend `Parcelable`**and** leave your default constructor

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;


public class MusicFile implements Parcelable {

    private Integer id;
    private String title;
    ...

    public MusicFile(Integer id, String title) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public MusicFile(){

    }

    protected MusicFile(Parcel in) {
        id = in.readByte() == 0x00 ? null : in.readInt();
        title = in.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        if (id == null) {
            dest.writeByte((byte) (0x00));
        } else {
            dest.writeByte((byte) (0x01));
            dest.writeInt(id);
        }
        dest.writeString(title);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<MusicFile> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<MusicFile>() {
        @Override
        public MusicFile createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new MusicFile(in);
        }

        @Override
        public MusicFile[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MusicFile[size];
        }
    };
}
```

The class `Parcel` is handled by Android when you pass objects in bundles like `bundle.addParcelableExtra(...)`. You should not attempt to handle these things on your own. When you call `addParcelableExtra()` Android uses these methods (`writeToParcel`, `describeContents`, etc.) to serialize your objects, but **it is completely up to the framework**. You should add these methods to help Android serialize your objects automatically (and save you from a lot of pain) but you keep your standards constructors, getters/setters, etc.

Comment: Of course! I forget that Java can have multiple constructors

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Parcel.obtain()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel#obtain()) to get a `Parcel`. Don't forget to do

> parcel.recycle()

after finishing using it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an empty constructor for parcelable. Your model should now look something like this:

```
 public static final Creator<MusicFile> CREATOR = new Creator<MusicFile>() {
    @Override
    public MusicFilecreateFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new MusicFile(in);
    }

    @Override
    public ClassModelInfo[] newArray(int size) {
        return new ClassModelInfo[size];
    }
};

// It's an empty constructor for parcelable 
private MusicFile() {

}

// This constructor is what parcel generates.
protected MusicFile(Parcel in) {
        Title = in.readString();
        Album = in.readString();
        Artist = in.readString();
        Path = in.readString();
        Genre = in.readString();
        Data = in.readString();
        artistID = in.readInt();
        if (in.readByte() == 0) {
            AlbumID = null;
        } else {
            AlbumID = in.readLong();
        }
        albumCover = in.readParcelable(Uri.class.getClassLoader());
    }
```